# Exception in Camel JMS Failed Premature EOF

Tags: apache-camel

please can you help me with this problem I am rarely presented

The execution of the JMS message listener failed. Causes by  Java.io.IOException Premature EOF

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by incorrect route definition. I have encountered this error when i was missing some '&' characters between parameters or when i didn't have 'jms:queue' or 'jms:topic' at the beginning.